# How can I implement an active current limit (with auto-recovery) for a solid state relay (SSR)?

Tags: power-supply, switches, relay, solid-state-relay

I am using a [G3VM-61QVH](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/307/Omron_12022020_G3VM_31QV_61QV_K319_E1_01-1928560.pdf) SSR which doesn't have a current limit feature. I would like to have this feature added through an external circuitry. What are the possible options for me?

Note: Typically an external fuse or current limiting resistor is suggested, but I am looking for an auto-recover feature (once the over-load is removed.) Something similar to the [LPD70](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/227/TELDS00378_1-2578075.pdf).

Another option was a load switch, but I would prefer isolation between control and load voltage.

Comment: What supply voltage (AC or DC and value)? What current limit value do you want? What volt drop is acceptable for the current limiting circuit (it will be a volt drop in series with the load)?

Comment: 1. DC supply voltage
2. Current limit ~0.6A
3. Volt  drop~1V

Comment: Is the polarity of the DC always the same?

Comment: No, I just realised the polarity of the DC supply can be positive or negative.